# Webmatrix - Creating two tables with the primary key from one

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I currently have the following SQL statement which creates an entry in my database, and auto creates the primary key. This works fine:

```
if (IsPost){
var sql = "INSERT INTO Property_Info (PropertyName) VALUES (@0)";
db.Execute(sql, Request["propertyname"]);
}
```

What I also need to do on the same page, is insert a record into a different table, using the primary key created in the above statement. is this possible, or will i need to do this on a separate page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can get the database ID you created with `db.GetLastInsertId()` and use that as a parameter in your next query.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.getlastinsertid(v=vs.111).aspx

I've found that you are best off casting it to an `int` too, so immediately after your `db.Execute()` line, try this:

```
int newId = (int)db.GetLastInsertId();
```

Comment: dude, yet again, quick and concise! work's a treat! You've just eliminated 2 pages and about 30 lines of code for me! many thanks